# Selenium vba return value of a clicked element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Currently using vba and selenium to automate some tasks in SAP and in a web based program that we access with edge chromium. Currently, my spreadsheet has a start button that opens an instance of SAP and starts a new instance of edge with 3 different tabs. This all stays open until i close the spreadsheet at the end of the day. Whenever i need to create an order, i click a button on my spreadsheet to begin this script and i enter a couple pieces of information that tells it which one of the three tabs i need to work from.

Now i finally get to my question….

Right now i double click on a field in the edge browser to select/highlight some text, copy to my clipboard, then paste in a userform on excel.

I thought that i could try an event listener right here for a mouse double click, it could return the element that was just clicked?  I have not found anything that covers how to return information of which element has focus or is selected with selenium.

Is this possible?

***Making some progress..

Still trying to figure out the mouse double click event, so the code below is from something else I had.  On this sample URL, the dew point, humidity, and precipitation all can be used for this example.  The goal is to be able to double click on the humidity and it capture the value.

This code, you double click to select, then shift+click and it will return the inner html.

Sample code:

```
Option Explicit

Public D As EdgeDriver

#If V10BA7 Then
    'declare virtual key event listener
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Long

#Else
    'declare virtual key event listener
    Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
    Public Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As Long) As Long

#End If

'Constants
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const VK_SHIFT = &H10  'SHIFT KEY

Public Const HubURL As String = "https://www.msn.com/en-us/weather/today/weather-today/we-city?el=0ZsYvXxKhYYMTPRM%2BTMX0UAWvqF%2FyQI9YQxk78YCuPFGYXNyxfjTFrNODP%2FkmqHR&ocid=ansmsnweather"

Sub StartEdge()

Dim elem As WebElement
Dim elemStr As String

    Set D = New EdgeDriver

    With D
        .Get HubURL
    End With
    
    Do Until GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyShift) And GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyLButton)
        DoEvents
        Loop

    Do While GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyShift)
        DoEvents
        Loop
       
    Set elem = D.activeElement()
    
    elemStr = elem.Attribute("innerHTML")
    
    MsgBox elemStr

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you can get the value by using HTML tag. Can you post sample code and sample url to reproduce the issue?

Comment: `driver.ActiveElement()` ?